Link to a specifc category?
As far as I understood I should be able to link to a certain category by url using:
mysite.com/category/
But simply said it doesn't work. I have to use link like
mysite.com/?cat=1
Meaning needing to know the id of the category.
Is this simply how wordpress works nowadays or how do I get the "old" behavior?

Try rebuilding you permalinks by going into 'Settings > Permalinks' changing them to something different than what they're set to then changing them back to what they are. (Or just hit save on the current screen)

You need to go to your permalinks under settings and change the option for structure to Post name.
